# Some infinite series involving hyperbolic functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

I have been working on a problem in Quantum Field Theory that involves some sums that I haven't been able to get a closed form. They all involve hyperbolic functions:

\begin{gather}
   \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^3} \coth \left(\frac{m\pi}{2x}\right)\,,\nonumber\\
    \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2} \operatorname{csch} ^{2}\left(\frac{m\pi}{2x}\right)\,,\\
     \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m} \coth \left(\frac{m\pi}{2x}\right) \operatorname{csch}^{2}\left(\frac{m\pi}{2x}\right)\nonumber\,.
\end{gather}

I have wondered if anyone knows how to evaluate them and could help me out.

Any references that may address the computation of them are very welcome, too.

Comment: Maybe you could find some luck with replacing the hyperbolic functions with their logarithmic definitions. Best possible case -- you get nice telescoping series. Worst case -- it won't help you, but it's at least better to work with. It is very probable that if the closed form exists, it is in terms of gamma, zeta, and other non-elementary functikns after further analysis

Comment: For the first sum, note that the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ is $\zeta(3)$.  That kind of puts the squash on any hope for an elementary form for that sum.

Comment: The first sum can be evaluated in closed form if $x=\sqrt{-n} $ and $n$ being a positive rational number.

Answer (score 1):

**Not An Answer.**
Such series probably have no explicit closed-forms for arbitrary $x$. But for $x=1/2$,
we have
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^3} 
=\frac{7\pi^3}{180},\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2\sinh(\pi n)^2} 
=\frac23G-\frac{11\pi^2}{180},\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n\sinh(\pi n)^2}=\frac\pi{30}-\frac{G}{3\pi}.
\end{aligned}
where $G=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$ denotes Catalan's constant.
*Proof.* The first sum is
$$
\sum_{m,n\ge1} \frac{1}{n^2(m^2+n^2)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n\pi\coth(\pi n)-1}{2n^4}
=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{m,n\ge1}\frac{m^2+n^2}{m^2n^2(m^2+n^2)}
=\frac{\pi^4}{72}.
$$
For the last two sums, explicitly compute $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z},n\ge1}\frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{3}G-\frac{\pi^4}{90}  ,
\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z},n\ge1}\frac{n^2}{(m^2+n^2)^3} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}G ,$ and it gives the claimed results.